# Godot, how to get the CollisionShape2D node from an Area2D node?

Tags: collision-detection, godot

I am trying to calculate one of the intersection points between 2 Area2D. I am following these instructions:

- https://godotengine.org/qa/12805/retrieving-the-collision-point-of-two-area2d-objects?show=12835#a12835

So I have to use the method `collide_and_get_contacts` from a Shape2D node.

But right now I only have the 2 Area2D nodes.

I am detecting the intersection on the signal [Area2D.entered_area](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_area2d.html#signals) and this signal is only sending me the other Area2D, not the Shape2D.

What is the way of getting the CollisionShape2D from a random Area2D? (It is ok if the Area2D has many CollisionShape2D and I get the first one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `area_entered` you can use `area_shape_entered`. I quote from the documentation:

> `area_shape_entered ( RID area_rid, Area2D area, int area_shape_index, int local_shape_index )`
>
> Emitted when one of another `Area2D`'s `Shape2D`s enters one of this `Area2D`'s `Shape2D`s. Requires `monitoring` to be set to `true`.
>
> `area_rid` the `RID` of the other `Area2D`'s `CollisionObject2D` used by the `Physics2DServer`.
>
> `area` the other `Area2D`.
>
> `area_shape_index` the index of the `Shape2D` of the other `Area2D` used by the `Physics2DServer`. Get the `CollisionShape2D` node with `area.shape_owner_get_owner(area_shape_index)`.
>
> `local_shape_index` the index of the `Shape2D` of this `Area2D` used by the `Physics2DServer`. Get the `CollisionShape2D` node with `self.shape_owner_get_owner(local_shape_index)`.